# I have added one custom attribute for product named percentage. How can I add that attribute to product price after adding that product into cart?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, addtocart, custom-attributes

I have tried below code. However its working fine but other products for which custom attribute is not being added from admin, I am not able to add to cart such products.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check logs. Is there any logs related to add to cart?

Comment: Try to add code instead of screenshot.

Comment: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/magento_23/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html","invalidateInfo": This is what I am getting in debug log

Answer (score 0):

**Put code in below condition**

```
if($percentage != ''){
     // here will go line no 13 to 21 code  
}
```

hope this helps you :)

Comment: It's not working.still same issue

Comment: answer updated. please try this

Comment: Now it's working fine for simple and  configurable products. But it's not working for other products like configurable and grouped product.